# How to use One Class for Multiple Listview Item Clicks

Tags: android, listview

This is my main code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_of_button);
ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
ImageButton btn2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
ImageButton btn3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
ImageButton btn4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
ImageButton btn5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
ImageButton btn6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
btn4.setOnClickListener(this);
btn5.setOnClickListener(this);
btn6.setOnClickListener(this);
}


  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    // if one of the image buttons is pressed...
    case R.id.imageButton1:
    case R.id.imageButton2:
    case R.id.imageButton3:
    case R.id.imageButton4:
    case R.id.imageButton5:
    case R.id.imageButton6:   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Listviewact.class);
        // pass ID of pressed button to listview-activity
        intent.putExtra("buttonId", v.getId());  
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    // here you could place handling of other clicks if necessary...        
    }
}

private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private ListView getListView() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
 }
 }
```

This is my listview code.

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Listviewact extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AlexBrush-Regular-OTF.otf");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int buttonId = getIntent().getIntExtra("buttonId", 0);
    int buttonIdx = getButtonIdx(buttonId);

    // find and set image according to buttonId
    int imageId = IMAGE_IDS[buttonIdx];        // image to show for given button
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

    // find and set listview imtes according to buttonId
    String[] items = LISTVIEW_DATA[buttonIdx]; // listview items to show for given button
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            if(position == 0)
            {
            //code specific to first list item    
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Information.class);
                         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

            if(position == 1)
            {
            //code specific to 2nd list item    
                     Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Information.class);
                         startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
                }
              });
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            //Or do whatever you need.
}


        public void onItemClick1(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




private void setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter adapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// a little helper to map ids to array indices 
// to be able to fetch the correct image and listview data later
private final static int[] BUTTON_IDS = new int[] {
    R.id.imageButton1, 
    R.id.imageButton2, 
    R.id.imageButton3, 
    R.id.imageButton4, 
    R.id.imageButton5, 
    R.id.imageButton6
};

// 6 images
private final static int[] IMAGE_IDS = new int[] {
    R.drawable.1,
    R.drawable.2,
    R.drawable.3,
    R.drawable.4,
    R.drawable.5,
    R.drawable.6
};

// 6 different sets of strings for the listviews
private final static String[][] LISTVIEW_DATA = new String[][] {
    {"First A", "First B", "First C", "First D","First E","First F"},
    {"Second A", "Second B", "Second C"},
    {"Third A", "Third B", "Third C"},
    {"Forth A", "Forth B", "Forth C"},
    {"Fifth A", "Fifth B", "Fifth C"},
    {"Sixth A", "Sixth B", "Sixth C"},
};

  // map button id to array index
  static private int getButtonIdx(int id) {
    for(int i = 0; i<BUTTON_IDS.length; i++) {
        if (BUTTON_IDS[i] == id) return i;
    }
    return 0;    // should not happen
}
 }
```

What i would like to do, which i am finding it hard is when any of my listviews are clicked they all go to the same layout but have different data/infromation this image is the best way to show you guys. http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/705/f6h9.png. I am thinking that if i can have one class which can be reused and not have like 50 activity slowing things down would be great.

The image is what i would like to do. If possible have text on one side i.e HOTEL: PETS,VIEWS,PARKING,CHILDREN. Then i would like to call different information for the reslut 
on the left hand side. NO pets parking YES etc.

Comment: I did something exactly like this for a project I'm working on. I can't write a full answer right now but make a Model class that contains a `List<Information>` with getters and setters. Then create an Adapter class which displays the Model class in the ListView. Use one layout, but create separate activities which use the model differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if your `layout` is same then you can use the same `Activity`, but then the code might get complex.

Are the `ListView` items dynamically generated as in the case of `Google Maps Places`, or are the options specifically decided by you beforehand? If the case is the former then you have to fetch data from a database as you can't code for all possiblities, and if it is the latter you can explicitly code too.

After that on the next page if you use database, then fetch data from a `SQLite database`, or if its the latter case use `Intent.getExtra(data)` for each data and assign those values to the `Textfields`.

If I understood your question, this should work.

Comment: This sounds just what am after.."Are the ListView items dynamically generated" sorry i dont understand this bit.

Comment: I meant are the listview items generated on the basis of a query? Like in the case when I query for restaurants in New York I get a dynamic list, and when I query for them in Chicago, I get another list. These are dynamic lists.

Comment: You can also have a layout showing only predefined items, like "Your phone operating system" showing 1. iOS 2. Android 3. Windows 8, which are not dynamic. If it helps please upvote and mark answered :)

Comment: Yes this is what i want to do have different list on different listview click i.e new york,chicago can you show me some code to get started

Comment: This is something best understood through a tutorial... http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html ... this is the best... it will teach you how to use SQLite database with a ListView